# Removing .aspx from URL with an IIS Version 6 server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-6

I have a asp.net application that is running on a server that has IIS 6 on it.  I want to set-up a redirect so that instead of my page reading www.google.com/About-Us.aspx it just has www.google.com/About-Us.  I've seen in IIS7 where you can just write a rewrite into your web config file, but I'm not having much luck with what to do for IIS6.  Has anyone else had this issue as well or know of a work around for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add URL Routing.
More about that (actually this is a solution you need) you can find [HERE](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-hide-remove-ASPX-extension-in-URL-in-ASPNet.aspx)
[Screenshot of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNyEY.jpg)